# why is it displaying incorrect no. of bindings supplied ? i have followed the code thoroughly

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to insert data into database the following is my code,

```
planet_data = [
    ("Mercury", " 0.330*10^24", "2439.5", "5427", "3.7", " 4.3", "1407.6", "4222.6", "57.9*10^6", "46.0*10^6", "69.8*10^6", " 88.0", "47.4", "7.0", "0.205", "0.034", "167", "0"),
    ("Venus", "4.87*10^24", "6052", "5243", "8.9", "10.4", "-5832.5", "2802.0", "108.2*10^6", "107.5*10^6", "108.9*10^6", "224.7", "35.0", "3.4", "0.007", "177.4", "464", "0"),
    ("Earth", "5.97*10^24", "6378", "5514", "9.8", "11.2", "23.9", "24.0", "149.6*10^6", "147.1*10^6", "152.1*10^6", "365.2", "29.8", "0.0 ", "0.017", "23.4", "15", "1"),
    ("Moon", "0.073*10^24", "1737.5", "3340", "1.6", "2.4", "655.7", "708.7", "0.384*10^6", "0.363*10^6", "0.406*10^6", "27.3", "1.0", "5.1", "0.055", "6.7", "-20", "0"),
    ("Mars", "0.642*10^24", "3396", "3933", "3.7", "5.0", "24.6", "24.7", "227.9*10^6", "206.6*10^6", "249.2*10^6", "687.0", "24.1", "1.9", "0.094", "25.2", "-65", "2"),
    ("Jupiter", "1898*10^24", "71492", "1326", "23.1", "59.5", "9.9", "9.9", "778.6*10^6", "740.5*10^6", "816.6*10^6", "4331", "13.1", "1.3", "0.049", "3.1", "-110", "79"),
    ("Saturn", "568*10^24", "60268", "687", "9.0", "35.5", "10.7", "10.7", "1433.5*10^6", "1352.6*10^6", "1514.5*10^6", "10747", "9.7", "2.5", "0.057", "26.7", "-140", "82"),
    ("Uranus", "86.8*10^24", "25559", "1271", "8.7", "21.3", "-17.2", "17.2", "2872.5*10^6", "2741.3*10^6", "3003.6*10^6", "30589", "6.8", "0.8", "0.046", "97.8", "-195", "27"),
    ("Neptune", "102*10^24", "24764", "1638", "11.0", "23.5", "16.1", "16.1", "4495.1*10^6", "4444.5*10^6", "4545.7*10^6", "59800", "5.4", "1.8", "0.011", "28.3", "-200", "14"),
    ("Pluto", "0.0146*10^24", "1185", "2095", "0.7", "1.3", "-153.3", "153.3", "5906.4*10^6", "4436.8*10^6", "7375.9*10^6", "90560", "4.7", "17.2", "0.244", "0.244", "122.5", "-225", "5"),
]
c.execute("INSERT INTO planetary_factsheet_metric VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )", planet_data)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> File "e:\Database\appdata.py", line 17, in <module>
>     c.execute("INSERT INTO planetary_factsheet_metric VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )", planet_data)
> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 18, and there are 10 supplied.
> ```

Comment: What "code" have you "followed thoroughly"?

Answer (score 2):

To insert from a list, you'll need `executemany`:

```
c.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO planetary_factsheet_metric VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? )",
    planet_data,
)
```

The 10 you're seeing is the number of planets you have, each with 18 columns.